# Asignar la ubicación de una base de datos excel obtenida de un texbox

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, vba

Tengo este código en el botón Aceptar del formulario

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Ruta As String
Ruta = Rutafrm.TextBox1.Value
End Sub

Este otro ya es en la macro

'Definir la ruta de la base de datos
PathDataBase = Me.Ruta.Text

Y ya esta es la conexión y consulta a la DB

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
conexionBD = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & PathDataBase

'Realizar la consulta a la tabla que queremos
consultaSQL = "Select * from Clientes where " & campotabla & complementobusqueda & "'" & nombrecliente & "'"
cn.Open conexionBD
Set datos = cn.Execute(consultaSQL)

En la linea  cn.Open conexionBD me sale error de autentificación al ejecutar la consulta

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Puedes guardar el valor del textbox llamando a su formulario y a l propio control. Algo tipo `Ruta = Userform1.Textbox1.Value` debería servirte

Comment: *En la linea cn.Open conexionBD me sale error de autentificación al ejecutar la consulta* Eso es que la conexión no está bien. Asegurate que la Path es correcta y que VBA la está cogiendo bien.

Comment: Como dije antes, el código funciona, lo único que tienes que hacer es cambiar `Me.Ruta.Text` por el nombre de tu `TextBox`, quizá: `Me.TextBox1.Text` si es que asi se llama, luego desde el botón llamar a esa función solamente `Call Test`.

Answer (score 0):

Esto debe servir.

Pones la ruta en una variable y luego la concatenas en la cadena de conexión.

```
Sub test()
    Dim PathDataBase As String, cnString As String
    Dim cn As Object
    
    PathDataBase = Me.Ruta.Text
        
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & PathDataBase
    
    cn.ConnectionString = cnString
    cn.Open
    cn.Close
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Pero ese PathDataBase necesito obtenerlo de un textbox un un formulario, o sea cuando se abre excel saco un formulario solicitando la ubicación de  la base de datos, la ruta en ese formulario necesito guardarla en esa variable PathDataBase

Comment: Es correcto, esa línea queda así: `PathDataBase = Me.Ruta.Text`

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas pero me sigue dando problemas<br/>'Definir la ruta de la base de datos
 ruta = Rutafrm.TextBox1.Value
 PathDataBase = Me.ruta.Text <br/>Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
conexionBD = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & PathDataBase <br/> me da error de autentificación

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas pero me sigue dando problemas: 'Definir la ruta de la base de datos ruta = Rutafrm.TextBox1.Value PathDataBase = Me.ruta.Text 'Definir la conexion, proveedor y ubicación de la BD
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.connection") conexionBD = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & PathDataBase me da error de autentificación cuando llamo la consulta

Comment: Es porque en tu cadena de conexión falta el `Data Source=`, observa el código de mi ejemplo, de hecho seria bueno que copies ese código y solo cambies `Me.Ruta.Text` por el nombre del TextBox de tu formulario.

Comment: si le corregí pero me sigue dando error, arriba coloqué el código corregido pero igual da error, no logro poner bien los textos en el formato del foro disculpen

Comment: Sigue dando el mismo error?, Ese código esta probado, por lo que debe funcionar simplemente cambiando `Me.Ruta.Text` por el nombre de tu TextBox, pero si estas haciendo algo adicional que no sabemos, entonces lo mejor es que edites tu pregunta y pongas el código final que te esta fallando.